# Javascript jQuery ajax submit default data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to submit default data when using $.ajax?

I have tried:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  // can't access anything here... (tried jqXHR.data but undefined)
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    // can't access anything here... (tried jqXHR.data but undefined)
  }
});
```

I need this so I can send my CSRF token, each time and when logged in submit the user ID each time. I prefer not to submit a token in headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had kind of the same problem. Solved by using beforeSend event. There everything is accessable.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ => beforeSend.

```
 beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the question state that the OP already tried that? Or do I misread it?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you want send your data and you don't want set header.

you can set your default data in $.ajaxSetup as follows. see [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm) how $.ajaxSetup woek.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: { // your default data here.
         username: "sakura",
         password: "Hadoken!!!"
     },
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

Comment: @onlineracoon I make the changes.